# angularjs - how to use ng-repeat element to get data from another set of data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Sorry, the titles is not clear at all, but I didn't really know a better title to explain what I'm tring to do.

Basically, I've this set of data:

```
$scope.data = [
    {"id": 0, "name": "Testing name 0", "type": 1, "details": {"pinned": true, "link": [1,2]}},
        {"id": 1, "name": "Testing name 1", "type": 0, "details": {"pinned": true, "link": [4]}},
        {"id": 2, "name": "Testing name 2", "type": 0, "details": {"pinned": true, "link": []}},
        {"id": 3, "name": "Testing name 3", "type": 0, "details": {"pinned": true, "link": []}},
        {"id": 4, "name": "Testing name 4", "type": 1, "details": {"pinned": true, "link": [4,0]}},
        {"id": 5, "name": "Testing name 5", "type": 1, "details": {"pinned": true, "link": []}},
        {"id": 6, "name": "Testing name 6", "type": 1, "details": {"pinned": true, "link": [1,2,3,4]}}
  ];
```

and this repeater to display only the rooms with type 1:

```
<ion-list class="list">
        <div ng-repeat="item in data">
            <ion-item class="item item-stable" ng-if="item.type==1">
                {{item.name}}
            </ion-item>         
            <div ng-if="item.type==1" ng-repeat="(key, value) in item.details">
                <div ng-repeat="linkID in value" ng-if="key == 'link'">
                    <ion-item class="item-accordion">
                        {{linkID}}
                    </ion-item>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-list>
```

as you can see from the code above, I'm printing a top level item with the name of all `"type:" 1`, and as a sublevel, all off the values inside `link: []`.

So far so good, but the values inside `link: []` are IDs of linked posts, and instead of 1,2 or 3 I'd like to print "Testing name 1", "Testing name 2", "Testing name 3" and so on...

I can't figure out the best way. All the data is there, but I just can't display it. I tried with another `ng-if`, but nothing. Any help?

here's an example: http://codepen.io/nickimola/pen/dMNawj?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ng-if` better use `filter`.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/fnfh3ww2/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [{
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Testing name 0",
      "type": 1,
      "details": {
        "pinned": true,
        "link": [1, 2]
      }
    }, {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Testing name 1",
      "type": 0,
      "details": {
        "pinned": true,
        "link": [4]
      }
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Testing name 2",
      "type": 0,
      "details": {
        "pinned": true,
        "link": []
      }
    }, {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Testing name 3",
      "type": 0,
      "details": {
        "pinned": true,
        "link": []
      }
    }, {
      "id": 4,
      "name": "Testing name 4",
      "type": 1,
      "details": {
        "pinned": true,
        "link": [4, 0]
      }
    }, {
      "id": 5,
      "name": "Testing name 5",
      "type": 1,
      "details": {
        "pinned": true,
        "link": []
      }
    }, {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "Testing name 6",
      "type": 1,
      "details": {
        "pinned": true,
        "link": [1, 2, 3, 4]
      }
    }];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <ion-list class="list">
      <div ng-repeat="item in data|filter:{type:1}">
        <ion-item class="item item-stable">
          {{item.name}}
        </ion-item>
        <div ng-repeat="linkID in item.details.link">
          <ion-item class="item-accordion">
            Lnked post--{{data[linkID].name}}
          </ion-item>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="item.details.link.length==0">
          <i>Nothing linked</i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the filter, but it doesn't solve my main issue: displaying the name instead of the ID for the sublevel

Comment: @Nick see my answer `{{data[link].name}}`

Comment: Ok sorry. I don't understand this **So far so good, but the values inside link: [] are IDs of linked posts**. I'm correct my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Think that is what you expected?

```
<ion-content ng-app="ionicApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ion-list class="list">
    <div ng-if="item.type==1" ng-repeat="item in data">
        <ion-item class="item item-stable">
            {{item.name}}
        </ion-item>         
        <div ng-repeat="link in item.details.link">
            <ion-item ng-if="data[link].name" class="item-accordion">
                {{data[link].name}}
            </ion-item>
            <ion-item ng-if="!data[link].name" class="item-accordion">
                Link not found: {{link}}
            </ion-item>
        </div>
        <ion-item ng-if="item.details.link.length == 0">
            Nothing
        </ion-item>
    </div>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: if the array is empty, shall i use ng-switch? lets say i want to display a message saying nothing is linked, fore xample

Comment: yep you can use ng-switch or ng-if. Btw you should lookup if the linked item exists. Edit my answer for this case

Comment: If doesn't work with ng-if="!data[link].name", nothing is displayed

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ONzXKE works for me. Shows Empty 99 in the Testing Name 4 list

Comment: it works because you added 99 that is not found as an ID, I need to display if the array is empty, and not if no link is found. If the array is empty, then I should have nothing found

Comment: urgs, oh yep my fault. edit my answer. Instead of `<div ng-if"..">` its need to be `<ion-item ng-if"...">`. Updated the pen as well

Comment: Adding ng-if="item.details.link.length == 0" works, but unfortunately it needs to be inside the repeater (i'm displaying the names as accordion list, so it cannot be outside or it wont be displayed when accordion is pressed and shown)

Answer (score 0):

You could load the links into the scope then reference them with the id (assuming they're in order).

```
<div ng-repeat="linkID in value" ng-if="key == 'link'">
    <ion-item class="item-accordion">
        {{links[linkID]}}
    </ion-item>
</div>
```

Comment: unfortunately they are random, i can link any post to another

Comment: Could you sort the links by id then?